# Stored Procedure with Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I have one Stored Procedure with different actions in it. For Eg - Insert, select, update all are in one stored procedure and I execute it using a if else condition.

```
BEGIN

if(@type = 'add')
INSERT INTO [dbo].[napme]
       ([firstname]
       ,[lastname]
       ,[Address]
       ,[City])
 VALUES
       (@firstname,@lastname,@Address,@City)


if(@type = 'select')
select * from napme

END
```

Now can I use that procedure in MVC using Entity Framework. If so how?

Once such method is mapping the parameters but I am unable to map @type
Can anyone suggest any easy way

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this

```
var courseList = ctx.Database.SqlQuery<YourEntityName>("exec ProcName @Param1", Param1).ToList<YourEntityName>();
```

Comment: `@Param1` is nothing but your parameter where you can pass your `@Type`

Answer (score 0):

If you plan on using Code-First EntityFramework then you can map Insert, Update and Delete operations to stored procedures if you wish.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder 
        .Entity<YourEntityClass>() 
        .MapToStoredProcedures();
}
```

With a SP example like so:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[YourEntityClass_Insert]  
  @param1 nvarchar(max),  
  @param2 nvarchar(max)  
AS  
BEGIN 
   INSERT INTO [dbo].[YourEntityClass] ([col1], [col2]) 
   VALUES (@param1, @param2)
```

Look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn468673.aspx) for more information.

If you plan on executing a SP for other reasons (non CRUD) then you will have to execute a SP as per bharats answer.